# How to set default props for array of object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to set default props for array of object.

```
breadCrumbItems= [{ href, onCLick, fieldText }, { href, onCLick, fieldText }]
```

I tried to default them using below but seems it is not working.

```
CedpBreadCrumbs.propTypes = {
  breadCrumbItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    href:PropTypes.string,
    onCLick:PropTypes.func,
    fieldText:PropTypes.string
  }))
};
CedpBreadCrumbs.defaultProps = {
  breadCrumbItems: [{
    href:'#',
    onCLick:(e)=>{e.preventDefault()},
    fieldText:'BreadCrumbItem'
  }]
};
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Copy/pasted into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-archimedes-79nui?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), appears to function. What isn't working for you?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing, the way u r using is correct way only. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props